# Understanding reference behaviour in c#

Tags: c#

I have a questions about the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var msg = new Message()
        {
            Description = new Description() { Key = 1, Value = "Foo"},
            ID = 1,
            Name = "MyMessage"
        };
        changeDescription(msg.Description);
    }

    static void changeDescription(Description descrToChange)
    {
        descrToChange = new Description() { Key = 2, Value = "Foobar" };
    }
```

Why does my msg has Description (Key = 1, Value = "Foo") after the method call?

Classes:

```
class Message
{
    public Description Description { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Description
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Edit: If I use the 'ref' keyword as some of you suggest, I get this error:

```
Error   CS0206  A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter
```

Comment: Some materials to study [Parameter Passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html), [Values vs References Types in C#](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: I would imagine this is probably a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: You can use the `ref` keyword with the `Message` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your method, you create a totally new instance of `Description`. A reference to this instance is stored in your local variable `descrToChange`.

`descrToChange`, as a parameter, is a copy of your reference variable `msg.Description`. The Original reference inside `descrToChange` is overwritten in your method, the reference inside `msg.Description` remains the same.

*** Solution #1: Use the already created instance ***

One solution could be to modify the members of the instance which your reference variable is already pointing to. You do not create a new instance in your method, but simple use the one already there:

```
static void changeDescription(Description descrToChange)
{
    descrToChange.Key = 2;
    descrToChange.Value = "Foobar";
}
```

*** Solution #2: Use the parent to modify its child ***

Another solution could be to use `Message` as a parameter:

```
static void changeDescription(Message msg)
{
    msg.Description = new Description() { Key = 2, Value = "Foobar" };
}
```

and call it like this:

```
changeDescription(msg);
```

*** Solution #3: Use `ref` to modify the reference (inside a variable) ***

If `msg.Description` would have been a field instead of a property, and you want to modify that reference inside `msg.Description` by the method, use `ref`. Be aware: use this keyword wisely:

```
static void changeDescription(ref Description descrToChange)
{
    descrToChange = new Description() { Key = 2, Value = "Foobar" };
}
```

and call this method with:

```
changeDescription(ref msg.Description);
```

This can only work if your property would have been a field, which I do not advice:

```
class Message
{
    public Description Description;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Quickly adding on to Martin's answer, instead of calling `new` within the method, `descrToChange.Key = 2; descrToChange.Value = "Foobar";` will get you the desired result, or pass the param with the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Better ways would be to pass a `Message` (assignment of message's `Description` is fine) or returning a `Description`. Opinion: `ref` should be an infrequently used keyword.

Comment: @JTY: Thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: @crashmstr: True. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Hey, If I use 'ref', I get this error: 
Error CS0206 A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref paramete

Comment: Did you try this ? It doesn't compile for me: 'A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter'

Comment: @GrayFox and another problem with using `ref`. Your code makes no sense as it is to set `Description` and then just clobber it with a different reference.

Comment: @GrayFox: You are right. I made the assumption your Description was a field, it was not. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @Jaco: No, I did not try this. I wright all code out of my head. I made an incorrect assumption. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does my msg has Description (Key = 1, Value = "Foo") after the
>   method call?

Because you didn't make use of the `ref` keyword.

```
static void changeDescription(ref Description descrToChange)
{
    descrToChange = new Description() { Key = 2, Value = "Foobar" };
}
```

Also you have to change your method call to the following one:

```
 changeDescription(ref msg.Description);
```

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
>   value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the
>   parameter in the called method is reflected in the calling method. For
>   example, if the caller passes a local variable expression or an array
>   element access expression, and the called method replaces the object
>   to which the ref parameter refers, then the caller’s local variable or
>   the array element now refer to the new object.

For further information about the `ref` keyword, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Now let's understand it a bit more:

```
descrToChange = new Description() { Key = 2, Value = "Foobar" };
```

In the above line of code we create a new `Description` object and we assign it to the `descrToChange`. However, this variable, `descrToChange` is passed to the method as a parameter and can hold references of an object of type `Description`. We can pass an object of type `Description` to the method and then alter it's data, but we can't change the reference to this object. If this was you intention, then you should had passed the parameter by reference.

Comment: Did you try this ?  It doesn't compile for me: 'A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter'

Answer (score 0):

You overwrote the reference. You can change the existing object instead.

```
static void changeDescription(Description descrToChange)
{
    descrToChange.Key = 2;
    descrToChange.Value = "Foobar";
}
```